# Should I be worried about connection attempts to "Private Network"?

Tags: network

I am a newbie to Little Snitch, and am unfamiliar with what I am seeing.
One thing that troubles me is an arc on the map display from the windward islands that says "Private Network."
It is certainly eyeopening to see how many information exchanges take place which I was previously oblivious to. It is easy to get paranoid because I don't have the context.

So I am asking the community if this private network is something I should be concerned about, i.e. a MITM hack, or is it normal?

Comment: Welcome on the great Internet. Warning: `Little Snitch` is a fantastic tool for people who are working in the network, protocols and security fields. For trained eyes only might I say. For everyone else, this tool may lead to headaches, anxiety and help calls.

Comment: The truth is that the Internet reached a very high level of pollution and it's not easy to open the eyes in such a polluted water. As an example, I receive an average of 55 straight attacks each day. Hopefully I know how to block and analyze them. But it wouldn't be a dream walk for every user of a PC on the Internet if they were informed of every attack they receive every day ( day and night ) .

Comment: Your analogy to polluted water describes my first reaction. I knew there's a lot  going on between the clicks, but I wasn't prepared for the torrent of parasites. Which is why I signed up for it. Eyes wide open. 

Comment: If you want some more help on a particular example of warning of `Little Snitch`, feel free to make a screen capture, as long as you don't exhibit private information. This might help a lot of users who might be tempted to open the eyes in **troubled waters** media don't talk of because they didn't dive there.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your offer. The list would be so long it I would not wish to impose on others' time. I will muddle through as best I can, unless something really weird crops up. It is like a window into a microscopic world previously unseen.

Comment: I like your relevant image “looking at the under world”.

Comment: I regress to the familiar. I am a Biologist.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal to have a "Private Network", yes.

"Private Network" in terms of Little Snitch means that the communication has occurred between network addresses that are usually not routed on the internet. This means that the private network is usually either devices on your local network (i.e. in your own house for example), or devices on a private network you connect to (for example a work VPN with servers that have these addresses).

In general, there's nothing particularly "worrying" about private networks. There's no reason to be paranoid.

Whether or not the actual traffic is benign or malicious requires further analysis. You would need to know more about the specific communication, the devices on your local network and any other private networks you connect to.

As this type of knowledge is harder to come by for non-IT professional home users, it can be that Little Snitch itself becomes a source of needless worry - unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address my question.